# Using Pyston to LLVM and then Emiscripten to Javascript

Tags: javascript, llvm, emscripten, transcrypt

I am beginner to Pyston. I even dont know what I am saying is possible or not. Kindly enlighten me if someone knows can we use Pyston (by Dropbox) to convert python code to LLVM bitcode and then covert that bitcode to Javascript using Emiscripten. Also if I want to create JQuery file. How is that possible to use $ in the Python Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alan Green pointed out, you can use [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) to have Python 3.5 code cooperate with JQuery. The problem with the dollarsign is solved by using an alias:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')

def start ():
    def changeColors ():
        for div in S__divs:
            S (div) .css ({
                'color': 'rgb({},{},{})'.format (* [int (256 * Math.random ()) for i in range (3)]),
            })

    S__divs = S ('div')
    changeColors ()
    window.setInterval (changeColors, 500)
```

Transcrypt isn't interpreted into JS but compiled in advance, so it runs as fast as JS.

The HTML is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="__javascript__/jquery_demo.js"; charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script>$ (document) .ready (jquery_demo.start)</script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black">
        <font face="arial" size = "8">
        <div>The</div>
        <div>quick</div>
        <div>brown</div>
        <div>fox</div>
        <div>jumps</div>
        <div>over</div>
        <div>the</div>
        <div>lazy</div>
        <div>dog</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Disclaimer: I am the initiator of the Transcrypt project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking into Rapydscript, what do you think of. There are different dialects of Rapydscript available, like rapydscript-ng. I am thinking to user Rapydscript directly. But when I import stdlib, it creates javascript with variables in some different language which gives error and I am stuck in.

Comment: I am quite certain that you can use JQuery from Rapydscript without problems. Don't know about stdlib, though. Rapydscript NG contains quite some improvements. Last time I looked, certain addtions to Rapydscript NG were merged in to Rapydscript, looks like there's some convergence here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using rapydscript now. I have tried it and now it seems working. I downloaded stdlib.js from their web. But my question still there, we(Python community) must come up with something comparing to Typescript and I am sure that Pyston will cover its place as its backed up by Dropbox. But unfortunately I dont know the way.

Comment: One thing more Rapydscript is way better than Transcrypt, perhaps for a newbee. Transcrypt creating very difficult output.

Comment: Since I work on Transcrypt, what do you mean by output? The JavaScript? Or the syntax reports? I've never heard anyone call it difficult, but we're always open to improvement...

Comment: if you generate same method with Transcrypt and then from Rapydscript using -m option. Where as baselib.js (in case of rapydscript) is added. the Rapydscript code is very clean.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback. Currently available are at least the following: PyPyJs, Brython, RapydScript, Skulpt, Transcrypt, each with its own unqiue approach and mix of simplicity and completeness. If you're just starting to learn Python, probably you should start with CPython first, since that is the 'standard'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you have existing Python code that you would like to use from within a web page. With a lot of work, it would be possible to use the toolchain you propose (Pyston/Emscripten) but there are easier ways.

This Infoworld article "[4 tools to convert Python to JavaScript](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3033047/javascript/4-tools-to-convert-python-to-javascript-and-back-again.html)" has some useful links.

Transcrypt looks particularly promising. There is even a live example of using [Transcrypt with jQuery](http://www.transcrypt.org/examples#jquery_demo).

Comment: I know this given link, but the problem, there is no good solution available (as far as I know). For example Rapydscript is in beta and has only 500 commits. Where as Brython is interpreter. So Pyston seems only viable solution to me.